# grep wildcards issue ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I have an input file named `test` which looks like this

```
leonid sergeevich vinogradov
ilya alexandrovich svintsov
```

and when I use grep like this `grep 'leonid*vinogradov' test` it says nothing, but when I type `grep 'leonid.*vinogradov' test` it gives me the first string. What's the difference between `*` and `.*`? Because I see no difference between any number of any characters and any character followed by any number of any characters.
I use ubuntu 14.04.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` doesn't match any number of characters, like in a file glob. It is an operator, which indicates 0 or more matches of the *previous* character. The regular expression `leonid*vinogradov` would require a `v` to appear immediately after 0 or more `d`s. The `.` is the regular expression metacharcter representing any single character, so `.*` matches 0 or more arbitrary characters.

Comment: ty, I misunderstood the meaning of wildcards in grep looks like

Answer (score 0):

`grep` uses regex and `.*` matches 0 or more of **any characters**.

Where as `'leonid*vinogradov'` is also evaluated as regex and it means `leoni` followed by **0 or more of** letter `d` hence your match fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) grep uses, short as regexp, not wildcards you thought. In this case, "." means any character, "*" means any number of (include zero) the previous character, so ".*" means anything here.

Check the link, or google it, it's a powerful tool you'll find worth to knew.